# Seeking offline map API like Google Maps for web?

Tags: javascript, software-recommendations, maps, offline, node-js

I'm looking for an offline map API for web like Google maps (because I know I can't use this offline). I currently have a program (using js and node.js) that uses the google maps api and google roads api to produce a map, and given a set of points, returns another set of points containing roads nearest to the given points, and plots this. I need to make all of this work offline.

I've been looking at offline solutions like Open Street Maps (which a lot of people suggest), but I can't seem to figure out how to plot things. I've also looked at JOSM, but is it possible to plot on JOSM using a program rather than directly on the interface?

I'm currently working on plotting roads in Taipei, so I've already downloaded MBTiles for this city, as per some suggestions I've looked at online. I'm not sure what to do with these tiles however. Is it possible to plot points/lines on these tiles, and is there a built in function (like google roads snap to roads) that finds the nearest road?

What I've tried: I have tried Open Street Maps, JOSM, Leaflet, OpenLayers, but I can't seem to be getting the hang of any of these. Which makes me think, what if these tools aren't what I'm looking for?

Question: How do I go about plotting lines on the above listed tools? What do I do with the tiles I've already downloaded? If there simply is no hope for me to do what I want to with the above listed tools, is it possible to use something else, or is my project a lost cause?

Comment: hi, if you have mbtiles data then you can display them directly in QGIS or on a mobile device - for Android there are apps like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osedok.gisdatacollector

Comment: but if you need to create new vector data then why not to use the Shapefiles here: http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/taiwan.html and work with the roads vector layer directly in a desktop GIS application like QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at MapBox.
works for Android and iOS https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/

Comment: does this work for web apps as well? I see you've linked the mobile offline site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at other data collection solutions that allow offline maps? I've tested [Collector for ArcGIS](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/) using offline maps on iOS. This does require an ArcGIS Online/ESRI account to serve your data and basemap. There is also [IntraMaps Roam](http://www.mapsolutions.com.au/intramaps/intramaps-roam.aspx) which I have not tested yet.

You can find a solution to work with some of the tools you listed. It just depends on how much time and programming experience you have.

Comment: thanks for responding! do you know where I can find additional help for the resources I've listed? I have programming experience in js, but not with map APIs. How can I get started?

Comment: @rohi101 If you want to stay on the Google platform you'll have to use their SDK for iOS or Android SDK. The best place to start is [Google Maps API for Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/) which you've likely been to for documentation for the maps API.

I also found this interesting blog with a solution. http://geospatialscott.blogspot.ca/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html

You'll have to do some more web sleuthing for 'offline maps' and see what you come up with.